# iOS CloudKit - Store NSData representations of classes or create individual records with individual fields?

Tags: ios, persistence, cloud, cocoa

I have an app that already locally archives user created objects and has for several years. Each archived object can have several nested objects or arrays of objects in it--all of which conform to NSCoding and are archived with NSKeyedArchiver.

Would it be wise to use the NSData objects I already have from local archiving and send them up to their own record or should I try to replicate the object graph with individual record fields and CKReferences for all the nested objects?